# Android downloaded drawable to Arraylist<Integer>

Tags: java, android

I am trying to load images which I download into a gallery view. Currently I am just trying to download the images (within my array) and load them into the imageviews in the getView() method of the adapter so that they display in the gallery

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        Drawable dr = null;

        try {
            dr = drawable_from_url(slImageLink[position],"jk");//String array of .jpg urls

            Log.d("slImageLink[0]",slImageLink[position]); //this prints the url of the image I am downloading into logcat
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        ImageView imgView = new ImageView(cont);
        imgView.setBackgroundDrawable(dr);
        imgView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(80, 70));
        imgView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        imgView.setBackgroundResource(GalItemBg);
        return imgView;
    }
}

public  Drawable drawable_from_url(String url, String src_name) throws java.net.MalformedURLException, java.io.IOException {
    return android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromStream(((java.io.InputStream)new java.net.URL(url).getContent()), src_name);
}
```

I dont get an error, i just never get the images loading into the imageviews they are blank, anyone can help please?

Comment: can you post the code where you download the images and add them to the Array?

Comment: hi friend, its already above, the public drawable which returns a drawable (dr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

download all drawable before calling getview method. after that in getview() assign drawable item from arraylist . To download drawables create a separate method in adapter class.

Answer (score 1):

Try this please :D Hope I can help you

```
public  Drawable drawable_from_url(String url, String src_name) throws java.net.MalformedURLException, java.io.IOException {
  URL url = new URL(url);
  HttpURLConnection mConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
  mConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
  mConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
  mConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  mConnection.setUseCaches(false);
  mConnection.setDoInput(true);
  mConnection.setDoOutput(true);
```

return Drawable.createFromStream(url.getInputStream(), src_name);
}

// Reminder!!!!

1. Remember to set policy before using httpurlconnection

   ThreadPolicy mThreadPolicy = new ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
   StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(mThreadPolicy);
2. And the manifest file

   asa'`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

But Usually I am not using in this way.
I will use HttpURLConnection to cache all the image I need to Context.getCacheDir();

[Click Here for the API Document for getCacheDir](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getCacheDir%28%29)

After I download to cache directory. I use it as normal. After the application unload, the memory will auto release :D